# Object respositioning with scrollbar

Tags: c#, winforms, position, scrollbar

I am having this problem.
I have a panel with horizontal scroll bar;
inside this form I have a few groupboxes (different sizes and locations) and a function to swap them around.
When I swap the first with the second it all works fine but as soon as I move the scrollbar a little bit and want to swap for example the 4th with the 1st
the location of the very first groupbox changes as if the left border of the form was where the scroll bar is positioned and not the actual left side, leaving a big gap between the first groupbox and the left margin.
Anyone knows what the problem might be?

Comment: The `Location` of the controls changes while the container is scrolled. Both the `X` and `Y` value will become negative when a Control is scrolled out of view.

Comment: Solved by setting
panel.HorizontalScroll.Value=0;